# Giving data/params with my function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
 var regfbnaam = $('#regfbnaam');
 $('#regnaam').focusin({param1: regfbnaam},removeClass);

function removeClass(e)
{
    param1.removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Error in console.log: param1 is nog defined. Means he doesn't get the value of my param1. What am i doing wrong here?

(trying to get a variable with a onclick event to my function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (tested)

```
function removeClass(e) {  
    var param1 = e.data.param1;
    param1.removeClass('hidden');
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var regfbnaam = $('#regfbnaam');
    $('#regnaam').focusin({param1: regfbnaam},removeClass); 
});
```

**Reference:**

[event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

[.focusin()](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This one works indeed. What i had to do is: http://pastebin.com/aFivFUYh

Would it be possible to simplify this? I'm searching a way but can't find any. When i focus in a typefield there is an image that pops up. When i focusout, image goes away. Thats what it has to do.

Comment: Why dont you do `$('#regnaam').focusin(function(){
regfbnaam.removeClass();
})`. If I would be in your place, I would have given same class to image and its associated image, to that I can handle each input in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function removeClass(e)
{
    $(e.data.param1).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you trying to do with that syntax. I would suggest a different approach:

```
var $el = $(el);
$el.on('focusin', function(){
    removeClass(e, {param1: regfbnaam});
});

function removeClass(e, params)
{
    params.param1.removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Untested, but I think it should work. Basically the idea is that you are binding a function to the element and then providing it with whatever arguments it needs.